# firewall-cmd error on polkit

Tags: firewall, policykit

I am trying to run `firewall-cmd --list-all` but i am receiving the response

> ```
> Authorization failed  Make sure polkit application is running
> or run the application as superuser.
> ```

I can see that `polkit` is running by `systemctl status polkit` but I do not know how to start it as superuser.  I am sure this is a lame question but i have been searching.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Is your user a member of the `sudo` group? are you executing the command locally, or remotely (via SSH for example)?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu.  Version is 20.10

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status polkit

Nov 06 21:30:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Nov 06 21:30:10 ubuntu polkitd[1671]: started daemon version 0.105 using author>

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps -aux | grep polkit
root        1671  0.0  0.4 235544  7604 ?        Ssl  21:30   0:00 /usr/libexec/polkitd --no-debug
ubuntu      2075  0.0  0.0   7732   796 pts/0    S+   21:42   0:00 grep --color=auto polkit

Comment: $ getent group sudo
sudo:x:27:ubuntu

Comment: @markum Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, comments are cleaned up/ removed sometimes. Could you edit the question and copy important info into it directly.

Answer (score 2):

duh.  I just needed to run the command with `sudo` or as root

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```